# Rails if-validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модель с полями

- title:string
- expiration:datetime
- kind:enum, значения - pub, priv.

Нужно, чтобы expiration назначался только если kind==priv. Как мне кажется, это надо делать с использованием валидаций, но где-то я не прав, потому что в базу пропускаются модели с kind=pub. Вот код модели:

```
class Diary < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notes
  enum kind: [:pub, :priv]

  validates :kind, presence: true
  validates :expiration, presence: false, if: :isPublic?

  def isPublic?
    kind == "pub"
  end

end
```

Возможно стоит как-то программно делать вместо datetime у pub nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`presence: false` делает не то, что вы думаете - этот параметр просто отключает валидацию наличия. Вам нужен валидатор `absence`

```
validates :expiration, absence: true, if: -> { kind.pub? }
```

P.S. В руби методы принято именовать в snake_case, то есть правильно будет `is_public`. Ещё привычнее для рубишного мира будет `public?`, так как в названии метода можно использовать вопросительный и восклицательный знак. Но в данном случае он особо не нужен - `enum` предоставляет всё из коробки.

Ещё один совет - не сокращайте.

```
enum kind: [:public, :private]
```

читается гораздо лучше, а пишется не намного дольше

Comment: Спасибо большое! 
Про snake_case учту, что касается сокращений - это костыль, чтобы не вызывать ошибку ArgumentError (You tried to define an enum named "kind" on the model "Diary", but this will generate a class method "public", which is already defined by Active Record.):

Comment: @kervart точно, не сообразила. Правильный костыль в этом случае выглядит скорее как `publik` :)